# What can block mousePressEvent or Event Filter Mouse Click Events?

Tags: python, qt, events, mouse, qtreewidget

I can't seem to get any mouse clicks in a QTreeWidget. I have tried...

- ...overriding mousePressEvent, but it never runs at all. Not even to log a message.
- ...using an event filer. It works for everything but mouse clicks.
- ...using delegates. Their editor events work fine, but only when over an item, which isn't enough
- ...making sure everything is being added to layouts. I used QTCreator and the output is using layout.addWidget(). I am also adding the widget instance to a layout in the main window.

I was able to use the answer to register the widget as an event filter for the QTreeWidget like so:

```
# In __init___
    # self.tree is the QTreeWidget
    self.tree.viewport().installEventFilter(self)



def eventFilter(self, target, event):
    """ 
    This widget is an event filter for the tree, so this function is triggered 
    automatically
    """
    # Print on right-click
    if (event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress and 
        event.button() == Qt.RightButton):
        print("Right Click")

    # Don't block/accept the event
    return False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because what you can see (and click) on `QTreeWidget` is actually it's `viewport()`. You sholud install event filter on it's `viewport()` instead.