# How can I select cells in a QTableView like characters in a QTextEdit?

Tags: qt

I'd like to build a hex editor-like view using a QTableView. Each cell will be the representation of a byte of data. How can I configure the QTableView selection behaviour such that it acts like a typical text edit control? That is, rather than selecting a rectangular region of cells, it should select the remaining cells on a line, the entire contents of any intermediate lines, and partial contents on the final line.

In diagram form (`x` is selected, `.` is unselected), I want this:

```
..................
......xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx......
..................
```

I do *not* want this:

```
..................
......xxxxxx......
......xxxxxx......
......xxxxxx......
......xxxxxx......
..................
```

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, I had success changing the default behaviour of the `QItemSelectionModel` by subclassing it and overriding the `select` method, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10920294/87207

Here's the key part of my code:

```
class RollingItemSelectionModel(QItemSelectionModel):
    def qindex2index(self, index):
        """ convert QModelIndex to offset into buffer """
        m = self.model()
        return (m.columnCount() * index.row()) + index.column()

    def index2qindex(self, index):
        """ convert offset into buffer into QModelIndex """
        m = self.model()
        r = index // m.columnCount()
        c = index % m.columnCount()
        return m.index(r, c)

    def select(self, selection, selectionFlags):
        # PyQt5 doesn't have method overloading, so we type switch
        if isinstance(selection, QItemSelection):
            # This is the overload with the QItemSelection passed to arg 0
            qindexes = selection.indexes()
            indices = []

            for qindex in qindexes:
                indices.append(self.qindex2index(qindex))

            if indices:
                low = min(indices)
                high = max(indices)

                selection = QItemSelection()
                for i in xrange(low, high):
                    qi = self.index2qindex(i)
                    # inefficient, but functional
                    # manually add all the bytes to select, one-by-one
                    selection.select(qi, qi)
        elif isinstance(selection, QModelIndex):
            # This is the overload with the QModelIndex passed to arg 0
            # since it's a single index, already works as expected.
            pass

        else:  # Just in case
            raise RuntimeError("Unexpected type for arg 0: '%s'" % type(selection))

        # Fall through. Select as normal
        super(RollingItemSelectionModel, self).select(selection, SelectionFlags)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the QItemSelection/QItemSelectionRange class for this purpose.

Create a new item selection model:

```
QItemSelectionModel::select( ... )
```

Then pass it to the view:

```
QAbstractItemView::setSelectionModel( ... )
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've read through the documentation for the QItemSelectionRange, and it seems to indicate that the behaviour captures the rectangular region: "this can be visualized as a two-dimensional block of cells in a table". Can you suggest what options I can provide to select the region described in my question?

Comment: I think this [this](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/model-view-selection.html) will help you.